# Is it possible to add multiple javascript objects with the same key to an associative array?

Tags: javascript, associative-array, single-page-application

I am working on a Javascript web application (SPA) with RESTful api on the back-end. In my client-side datacontext I want to add objects to my model graph and then send the whole graph to server at once.

Suppose the following example:

I have a `Person` object in my model which itself has an array of say `PhoneNumbers` as a property. Now I load a `Person` from api for edditing and map it to my model. Suppose I want to add some phone number objects to my `PhoneNumbers`. For this I add each number e.g. `{"id": 0, "number": 6536652226}` with an id of zero to my client model and send the whole graph to server when user clicks save. In server I add the objects with the id of zero (new objects) to database with auto-incremented ids.

I am doing my project based on a tutorial. They do something like this to add objects to context:

```
                var items = {},
                    // returns the model item produced by merging json obj into context
                    mapJsonToContext = function (json) {
                        var id = mapper.getJsonId(json);
                        var existingItem = items[id];
                        items[id] = mapper.fromDto(json, existingItem); //returns the mapped obj
                        return items[id];
                    },
                    add = function (newObj) {
                    items[newObj.id()] = newObj;
                    }
```

The problem is that if I use this method I wouldn't be able to remove by id the newly-added-not-yet-saved items in client-side 'cause all the ids are zero!

Any suggestions to fix this, or do I need a totally different approach?

Comment: why not have the server return the incremented version and then work on that?

Comment: a) there are not "associative arrays", there are unordered object b) No, you won't be able to add one key twice

Comment: @ben336 For this to achieve with every child item added to my model I should save it to db. Then what if user wants to cancel editing the model? I should again hit the server and delete newly added children which I think it's not efficient as long as I can send the whole graph at once when user decides to save the whole model object.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, two little misconceptions I've spot:

1) Forget about "associative arrays". Numeric arrays are the only kind arrays you have; the other constructs are just "objects" (this is not PHP).

2) If it's JSON it's a **string**, not an object.

Other than that, you can of course use an arbitrary value to represent "new" (though I'd probably use `null` rather than `0`) as soon as you don't use such value to uniquely identify the yet-to-add item. E.g., this is just fine:

```
[
    {"id": 0, "number": "6536652226"},
    {"id": 0, "number": "9876543210"},
    {"id": 0, "number": "0123456789"}
]
```

This is not:

```
// WRONG!!!!
{
    0: "6536652226",
    0: "9876543210",
    0: "0123456789"
}
```

}

And of course you cannot find numbers by ID if they still don't have an ID. You need to choose:

- Retrieve the generated ID from DB and update your local data
- Delete by number

Comment: Retrieve the generated ID from DB and update your local data: For this to achieve with every child item added to my model I should save it to db. Then what if user wants to cancel editing the model? I should again hit the server and delete newly added children which I think it's not efficient as long as I can send the whole graph at once when user decides to save the whole model object.

Comment: Delete by number: I use this method for different models. Naturally they all don't have number properties on them.

Comment: @Pejman - Sorry if I misread something, I read "API" and thought stuff was being sent to server.

Comment: @Pejman - If not all items have a recognisable label, what does the GUI to delete stuff look like?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `localId` property on newly created client-side objects, and use that as your key when reconciling server returned-data. Obviously the server would have to return this `localId` to you.